# How to find who has birthday based on two string filds "day" and "month" in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this datamodel in mongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : "KPu78LNXYKfraRF94",
    ...
    "aboutPage" : {
        ...
        "birthDay" : NumberInt(27),
        "birthMonth" : NumberInt(5)
    }
}
```

I want to find all users who will have birthday tomorrow.
Is it possible to generate DateTime field from "birthDay" and "birthMonth" and find the documents? The year is not important at all, I do not have data about it.
Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: Have a look at $dateFromParts: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/N3gOviBxk9J    or https://mongoplayground.net/p/bLG0ONs5sh3

Comment: Is it really necessary to convert to date for that test?  If you are looking for people whose birthday is a specific day, an equality test of both fields should suffice, and would be serviced by an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconstruct the birthdate in proper date object in current year using `$dateFromParts`. Then, compute the difference in days using `$dateDiff` and get birthdates that is -1 day from now (i.e. birthdate is tomorrow)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      birthDate: {
        "$dateFromParts": {
          "year": {
            "$year": "$$NOW"
          },
          "month": "$aboutPage.birthMonth",
          "day": "$aboutPage.birthDay"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "daysFromToday": {
        "$dateDiff": {
          startDate: "$birthDate",
          endDate: "$$NOW",
          unit: "day"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      daysFromToday: {
        $gte: -1,
        $lt: 3
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "daysFromToday",
      "birthDate"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j1hwnaioxR1)

Comment: It looks like this is what I need. Thank you! 
Only one thing: I get birthday which is precicely -1 (number of days) day, but if I want to get in the period (today - 3days < birthDay <= today), is it possible?

Comment: @podeig updated the answer to select in a period

Comment: Nice! I works properly! Thank you for your help! Have a nice day! :-)